# Make datasets by loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to learn how to make a loop in R

I have this:

```
sigma2 <- 0.4
a0 <- -0.1260805
b <- 0.1260805
tt <- 1:50, 1:50

z <- rnorm(50, 0, sigma2)
y <- rep(1, 50)
for(i in 1:50){
  y[i]=exp(a0 + b*tt[i])*exp(z[i])
}

y
```

and I want to kind of test the code above 1000 times, since I want to test the hypothesis at the 0.05 level

can I treid this, and seens to be wrong:

```
aa <- rep(1, 1000)
for(i in 1:1000){
  y[i]=exp(a0 + b1*tt[i])*exp(z[i])
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Since R is vectorized, you don't need a for loop--you can do `y = exp(a0 + b * tt) * exp(z)` - assuming that `a0`, `b`, `tt` and `z` each have either the same length or length 1.

Comment: For  this question, it would help a lot if you could make it fully reproducible. Can you share sample values for `sigma2`, `a0`, `b`, `tt` and `z` so that we can see what your inputs are?

Comment: yes! sigma2 <- 0.4, a0 <- -0.1260805, b <- 0.1260805, tt <- 1:50, 1:50

Comment: It would also be really nice if you could explain more about your goal... in your first set of code you clearly have 50 different z values (and presumably 50 different `tt` values too?), and those are what change each iteration. In your second example, you want to use `1000` instead of 50, but you don't show any difference in `z` or `tt` - you'll need to do something to get their lengths up to 1000. Or maybe you want to do the 50 thing 20 times, with new `rnorm` values for z each set of 50? Or something else?

Comment: (Don't bother answering in comments - click the "edit" button at the bottom of your question and edit the needed info directly into your question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want (or at least closer):

```
# re-write original code with vectorization:

n <- 50
sigma2 <- 0.4
a0 <- -0.1260805
b <- 0.1260805
tt <- 1:n

z <- rnorm(n, 0, sigma2)
y <- exp(a0 + b*tt)*exp(z)

# do it 20 times
result <- replicate(20, exp(a0 + b*tt)*exp(rnorm(n, 0, sigma2)))
```

`result` is a 50x20 matrix - one column per repetition.